# Using Sed with Regex

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I would need to edit the values in a file delimited by colons (`:`)

I would like to replace the contents of the file by using regular expression.
After a grep to confirm that the item exist in the file system. I would like to edit the contents inside it by using sed.

I am open to the use of others tools. That would help me.

EDIT:

So far i have been trying to use sed to modify the contents in the text file in test.txt.
The current solution i could think of is sed.

```
 sed -i "s/^\($newEvent:$newPerson:[^:]*\):[^:]*:/\1:$newQty:/" test.txt 
 echo "item Qty has been updated successfully!"
```

Is there a way i am able to edit the content after a string matching of event && person and modify the contents of that line which matches.

Before any input content in text file

```
Birthday Party:John Harris:1:10:1

Enter Event: Birthday Party
Enter Person: John Harris


a)  Update Event
b)  Update Person
c)  Price
d)  Update Item brought
e)  Update Quantity Sold 
f)  Back to main menu
Please enter your choice: d
New Qty Sold : 38
Qty Sold  has been updated successfully!

a)  Update Event
b)  Update Person
c)  Update Item brought
d)  Update Quantity Sold
e)  Back to main menu
Please enter your choice: f
```

After input content in text file

```
 Birthday Party:John Harris:1:10:1
```

Comment: What file? What values? Please show us an example of your input and desired output.

Comment: Sorry but it is still not clear. What is in `test.txt`? What is this "last item" which you "cant seem to successfully change"? Also,please explain what you're actually trying to do, what's the big picture?

Comment: I don't know whether this is for an exercise and I don't want to assume; but if this is for actual production work, I think you should consider using a database rather than a flat plaintext file.

Comment: @JosephR. yes this is a exercise which i am currently stuck with. I would have use sqlite  if this is a actual production env

Comment: @LennonChia In that case, is the use of `sed` mandatory? If so, please specify this in your question so that people don't volunteer the use of other tools.

Comment: @JosephR. thanks for your input i have specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what exactly it is you want, but how about using read or awk?

```
echo -e "Happy Birthday:Mom Annie:12.99:197:101\nMeow Meow:Dad:11.11:1:1" | while IFS=: read -r event person date num1 num2 _ ; do echo $person; done

echo -e "Happy Birthday:Mom Annie:12.99:197:101\nMeow Meow:Dad:11.11:1:1" | awk -F: '$1 ~ /Happy.*/{print $1, $3, $NF}'
echo -e "Happy Birthday:Mom Annie:12.99:197:101\nMeow Meow:Dad:11.11:1:1" | awk -F: '$1 ~ /Happy.*/{print $0}'
```

Relevant: http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt

Consider rephrasing your question by showing the input and desired output.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear i have edited my question. Thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex text munging tasks consider using e.g. [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) or [Python](http://python.org/), or even `awk` (presumably in the base install of your system). `sed(1)` is fine as far as it goes, but it's syntax is arcane (and more suited for one-shot tasks, IMVHO).